# Waste less screen real estate in the close votes queue

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, vote-to-close, review

In the review queue for close votes, about half my screen is devoted to things other than the text of the question. On my setup, I count a whooping 500 pixels lost to the SE header bar, the generic line with the huge buttons, the review tab header, bar with the task buttons, and the detailed explanation of the task.

[image: unscrolled page]

Ok, so let me scroll down to have the question title at the top, so I can see the question and its comments.

[image: scrolled page]

Still a waste of over 200 pixels for the task explanation alone, plus about 50 for the task button bar. I can see the point of having the task buttons permanently visible is good. Keyboard shortcuts would be better, but I'm willing to sacrifice 5% of my screen height. It's that additional 20% that really rankles.

Please do not include the task explanation in the part of the page that's permanently visible. (Yes, I know I can hide it by clicking “less”, but it's yet another click in what's already a mouse-heavy task.)

<sub>And, more generally, not wasting so much screen real estate all the time would be nice. Scrolling down by a few lines is required when entering almost every Stack Exchange page.</sub>

Comment: Is the less/more section always stuck open? When I review the explanation is always closed by default, with an option to expand (more).

Comment: @Tim It doesn't stick for me (Chrome 21). Or rather, I think it sometimes sticks, and then comes back expanded. I can't figure out why. It seems to stick on the other queues.

Comment: The instructions default to "expanded" if you've ever reviewed a post in that queue before, excluding "Not Sure" reviews.

Answer (score 3):

You really should only have to click (less) once per queue per site. If you have to click it more often, file a bug report.

Comment: I've clicked around a lot, and now it seems to stick folded. Clicking “less” then clicking one of the buttons seems to reliably switch the default setting to folded, but then sometimes it switches back to unfolded for no reason I can discern. I'm still maintaining my feature request: even if it's unfolded, it should scroll out.